# Writing double in console C#

Tags: c#, parsing, console, double

I need your help about C#.
I'm creating this program:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You weight is: ");
        double weight = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Your weight on Moon is: + {0}",weight*0.17);
     }
```

And the problem is, when I start the program and input, for example 35.9, a number for the weight, the program crashes.

Comment: What is your error, if you're getting one? I can run your snippet w/o problems. e.g. input of 150 gives me 25.5. It will only crash if I hit enter w/o entering a number first. You don't have error checking so be careful. There are million ways to crash your app.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't crash. It closes.

You need to place `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the method if you want the window to stay open long enough to read the message.

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You weight is: ");
    double weight = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Your weight on Moon is: + {0}",weight*0.17);

    Console.ReadLine();  // waits for input, allowing you to read the message
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put breakpoints through the program, you can see it writes to the console, you just don't get an opportunity to see it.

Wait for a key using this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
ConsoleKeyInfo c = Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your help. I found out that in my general computer settings i have chosen comma as a decimal symbol and when i wrote in the console i used full stop.
So this is the reason why it closes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it'll definitely work:

```
Console.WriteLine("You weight is: ");
double weight;
double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out weight);
Console.WriteLine("Your weight on Moon is: + {0}", weight * 0.17);
```

Comment: It `Parse` fails to parse, so will `TryParse`. The only difference between OP's code and yours is that his will terminate with an unhandled exception, whereas yours will display `0`. Neither is a good solution. You should be checking the return value of `TryParse` and acting accordingly.

Comment: @dcastor - you are right about checking the return value.
Thanks for clarifying